# Adding new MySQL columns with matching data to original columns

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create columns in a MySQL table and insert data into them. I already have some data inside of the table, I would like to add more. I am not sure how I would go about adding the other data. If someone could help me out, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

My Source code looks like this:

```
 if($is_array($asinXML){
    foreach($asinXML as $asinXml){
        $asinXmlLoaded = simplexml_load_file($asinXml);
        foreach($asinXml->GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult as $asinItem){
            if(isset($asinItem['ASIN'])){
            $asinValue =  $asinItem['ASIN'];
            } else {
            $asinValue = '';
            }
            $asinErrorFound = 'Success' != $asinItem->attributes()->status;
            if($asinErrorFound = TRUE){
                $asinErrorFoundVal = 'Yes';
            } else {
                $asinErrorFoundVal = '';
            }
            if($asinErrorFoundVal == ''){
                if(isset($asinItem->Product->LowestOfferListing->NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered){
                $numberOfSellers = $asinItem->Product->LowestOfferListings->LowestOfferListing->NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered;
            } else {
                $numberOfSellers = '';
            }
```

My Sql table looks something like this so far :

```
UPC          ASIN        SalesRank
Value        Value1      Value2
```

I need to be able to insert a insert another column, then populate the column with information that corresponds to the ASIN Value. If that doesn't make sense, comment and i will elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Please add your PHP source code

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column (or columns) using `ALTER TABLE` statement. e.g.

```
 ALTER TABLE mytable ADD my_new_col INT COMMENT 'my new column' ;
```

If you want to initialize that column on all of the rows that are already in the table, you can populate it with the value from another column on the row with an `UPDATE` statement:

```
 UPDATE mytable SET my_new_col = some_old_col ;
```

If you just want to add a new row to the table, you can use the `INSERT` statement:

```
 INSERT INTO mytable (my_new_col) VALUES (42);
```

Comment: How would i go about matching the row to a value. I will update the question with some of my source code.

Comment: The usual way of locating/identifying a row to be updated is by matching a value stored in a column, e.g. `WHERE mycol = 'somevalue'`.

Comment: I updated my code. If you don't understand my question, i will explain. Just comment

Comment: `UPDATE mytable SET newcol = 'somevalue' WHERE ASIN='Value1'`

Comment: Thanks man.. How would i just go about adding values? The initial column insert would be done with a value, but then how would i go about entering a value where ASIN = 'Value1'

Answer (score 0):

you can ADD a calculated Column with the desired value.

If ASIN is numeric and you want to add taxes

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD MyNewColumn AS (ASIN * 1.08)
```

Comment: $asin is a variable. All I want to do is find a way to match the two asins so they are identical and add a price to that row. Would I have to add the Price column in the original table?